# Draw a border around X forwarded windows

Tags: ssh, x11, gui

When opening remote gui applications over ssh (X11 forwarding), is there a way to draw a visual indication of the remote in the window such as a red frame around it, display the hostname somewhere, or even change the theme ?

I'm using gnome shell, and windows opened on the server and the client are easily confused because they look identical.

Comment: Remote windows should have the hostname added to their title by default; isn’t that the case on your system?

Comment: Some have `(on <hostname>)` added, but a counter example is the file manager `nautilus`, which doesn't.

Comment: I must admit I know of no method other than modifying the source code of a window decorator, but I'm optimistic some desktop environment's window decorators can be configured / themed to do what you want :) Small problem: Even someone who knows how to do that would need to know what is doing the window decoration, so what desktop environment are you using?

Comment: I'm on vanilla ubuntu 22.04, so GNOME. The problem with theming is that not all applications respect env variables such as `GTK_THEME` (so e.g. using a dark theme on the client and a light theme on the server is a half-baked solution and even more confusing).

Comment: OK the good news is that you can probably script gnome-shell to add some decoration to the windows whose properties suggest they're remote, the bad news I don't think anyone has done that before. How do you like JavaScript?

Comment: I try to stay as far away of js as much as possible, but I'm curious now: what do you mean by scripting gnome-shell (do you have a reference on that) ?

Comment: @t-bltg I kind of have the same attitude towards JS, but it is the scripting language of `gnome-shell`, which allows you to do things like modifying borders. there's a large canon of user scripts for gnome-shell (which is a blessing and a curse, imagine the average software quality, and remember that a script misbehaving might mean you can no longer interact with your computer). I don't use GNOME myself, but see https://github.com/mipmip/gnome-shell-extensions-highlight-focus for an example of such a border-setting extension. [gjs docs](https://gjs.guide/extensions/development/creating.html)